# Preventing unauthorized writing to parts of server

Tags: design, authentication, client-server, http-request

Say I have two members which share a server. Both members have a game that is accessible to anyone and after playing, it records high scores by sending a request to write to a file on the server. However game A should only be allowed and to write to its own file as well as game B. Is there any way to authenticate which game/file is making the request to write to the file. Say maybe when the game file is requested from the server, I could add a unique token with it that identifies it and if tampered with, would invalidate it.

Comment: If the two games each run under a separate "user"-account, then the normal account protection mechanisms should be sufficient to keep the files of the two games separated.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify which operating system you are using, and which protocol should be used between clients. As mentioned in the comment by Bart best thing is to create different user accounts.

You marked the question with http-request, so if the protocol shall be HTTP, you should look into learning more about WebDAV protocol, which will allow you to store/retrieve files to/from a server using http.